# API should return IEnum with array type wrapper

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to transform my API return result

```
{ "type": "animal" , "age": 3 }
```

into

```
{ "myAnimal": [ "type": "cat", "age": 3 ] }
```

I tried doing

```
var myAnimal = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { MyAnimal = originalResult });
```

and return it

However, the API return type is set up as `<IEnumerable<AnimalModel>` whereas variable `myAnimal` is string type after `JsonConvert`. So there's a conflict.

I still want to return IEnum, is there anyway for me to work on this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json you want is not valid. But if you want to convert an object to an array, IMHO , the easiest way is to parse your origional result

```
    var origAnimal = new { type = "animal", age = 3 };

    var newAnimal = new JObject();
    newAnimal["myAnimal"] = new JArray(JObject.FromObject(origAnimal).Properties()
                                                           .Select(jo => new JObject(jo)));

    var json = newAnimal.ToString();
```

valid json

```
{
  "myAnimal": [
    {
      "type": "animal"
    },
    {
      "age": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

or you could be needed this json

```
var newAnimal = new JObject();
    
newAnimal["myAnimal"] = new JArray( JObject.FromObject(origAnimal));
var json = newAnimal.ToString();
```

json

```
{
  "myAnimal": [
    {
      "type": "animal",
      "age": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

or you have acces to API you will have to change the input parameter to JObject. In this case you don need to parse

```
public IActionResult MyApi(JObject  myAnimal)
{
 var newAnimal = new JObject();
 newAnimal["myAnimal"] = new JArray(myAnimal.Properties().Select(jo => new JObject(jo)));
...
}
```